# Polars: change a value in a dataframe if a condition is met in another column

Tags: python, python-polars

I have this dataframe

| one | two |
| --- | --- |
| a | hola |
| b | world |

And I want to change *hola* for *hello*:

| one | two |
| --- | --- |
| a | **hello** |
| b | world |

How can I change the values of a row based on a condition in another column?

For instance, with PostgreSQL I could do this:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET two = 'hello' WHERE one = 'a';
```

Or in Spark

```py
my_table.withColumn("two", when(col("one") == "a", "hello"))
```

I've tried using `with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("one") == "a").then("hello"))` but that changes the column "one".

EDIT: I could create a SQL instance and plot my way through via SQL but there must be way to achieve this via the Python API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were really close with `with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("one") == "a").then("hello"))` but you needed to tell it which column that should be.

When you don't tell it which column you're referring to then it has to guess and in this case it guessed the column you referred to.

Instead you do

```
(df 
    .with_columns(
        two=pl.when(pl.col('one')=='a')
                .then(pl.lit('hello'))
                .otherwise(pl.col('two')))
)
```

This uses the **kwargs input of `with_columns` to allow the column named to be on the left of an equal sign as though it were a parameter to a function. You can also use alias syntax like this...

```
(df 
    .with_columns(
        (pl.when(pl.col('one')=='a')
                .then(pl.lit('hello'))
                .otherwise(pl.col('two')))
            .alias('two')
                )
)
```

Note that I wrapped the entire when/then/otherwise in parenthesis. The order of operations around when/then/otherwise and alias is weird so I find it's best to always completely wrap them in parenthesis to avoid unexpected results. Worst case scenario is you have redundant parenthesis which doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: 100%. This is what I was looking for. So simple but I completely missed it. Very interesting re the wrapping! Many thanks indeed

Answer (score 3):

You need to name the expression to overwrite the existing `two` column, either using `.alias()` or a named arg `.with_columns(two = ...)`

You also need to provide `.otherwise()` as the default is `None`.

You want to use the existing column value when the condition is not true, hence `.otherwise("two")`:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"one": ["a", "b"], "two": ["hola", "world"]})

df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("one") == "a")
     .then(pl.lit("hello"))
     .otherwise("two")
     .alias("two")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ one ┆ two   │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ hello │
│ b   ┆ world │
└─────┴───────┘
```

The `.then()` branch generates the name, so another option is to invert the logic and put the column inside `.then()` which allows polars to infer the name for you.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("one") != "a")
     .then("two")
     .otherwise(pl.lit("hello"))
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ one ┆ two   │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ hello │
│ b   ┆ world │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a different solution which uses df.filter to get the idexes of the row to be modified, then a simple for-loop to apply the trasnformation. I know loops are not the best for speed. This is just to give an alternative solution. It is not the best solution.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'one':['a','b'], 'two':['hola','world']}).with_row_count()

s = list(df.filter(pl.col('one') == 'a')['row_nr']) #get indexes of filtered rows
for idx in s: #change all the selected rows
    df[idx,'two'] = 'hello'


print(df)

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ one ┆ two   │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ str ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ a   ┆ hello │
│ 1      ┆ b   ┆ world │
└────────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient. Might as well use plain python.